# I am unable to parse an HTTP response body from Dynamics CRM, it keeps returning as unicode characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, dynamics-crm, httpresponse

I am unable to get the data in the response of my HTTP GET request to Dynamics CRM in a format that is readable. It always returns as unicode characters (ie.body:'\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000�\m�۸\u0011�+Ķ=\��Z���\u0004A7/�\u000b ... '

When I send this same exact GET request in Postman, the body of the response I receive is formatted in a readable way and returns all of the KnowledgeArticles that I need - so (as far as I know) the http request is fine (as long as authorization token is kept current).

I am just totally stuck on how to parse this unicode data in my response body in to readable text that I can use in my code logic to return the right results to the user.

Below is my code for parsing calling the get request and parsing response

```
const restify = require('restify');
const errors = require('restify-errors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const request = require("request");
const stringify = require('stringify');



const server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'restify headstart'
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API is running on port ${port}`);
});

ar options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://########.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/knowledgearticles',
  qs: { '$select': 'content,title' },
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     Connection: 'keep-alive',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     cookie: '###################',
     Host: '#####.crm.dynamics.com',
     'Postman-Token': '#######',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.13.0',
     Authorization: 'Bearer ################# buncha crap #####',
     Accept: 'application/json'
    } 
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  // below are all of my attempts at parsing 'response'

  * let aaa = response;
  * let aaa = response.toJSON();
  * let aaa = JSON.stringify(response);
  * let aaa = response.toString();
  * let aaa = response.toJSON(body);

  * let aaa = response.setEncoding('binary');
  * let aaa = aaaa.toJSON();

  // none of the above result in my response logging into readable text

  console.log(aaa);
});
```

Comment: You got compressed `response`, remove `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'` header or decompress your `response` or add `gzip: true` to `request` options

Comment: Cool! this worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @ponury-kostek - would you mind posting that comment as an answer?

Comment: @jsbueno posted as requested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got compressed `response`, remove `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'` header

```
const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://contactcenter.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/knowledgearticles",
    qs: {"$select": "content,title"},
    headers: {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "cookie": "...",
        "host": "contactcenter.crm.dynamics.com",
        "postman-token": "...",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
        "authorization": "Bearer ...",
        "accept": "application/json"
    }
}
```

or add `gzip: true` to request options

```
const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://contactcenter.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/knowledgearticles",
    qs: {"$select": "content,title"},
    headers: {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "cookie": "...",
        "host": "contactcenter.crm.dynamics.com",
        "postman-token": "...",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
        "authorization": "Bearer ...",
        "accept": "application/json"
    },
    gzip: true
};
```

or manually decompress your `response`

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: I apologize. I am very new to this. I will accept now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `JSON.parse()`.

Here's a full example created by [Jason Lattimer's CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder).

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/knowledgearticles?$select=content,title", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var content = results.value[i]["content"];
                var title = results.value[i]["title"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```